# react leaflet Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:39)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

```
Failed to compile.
```

./node_modules/@react-leaflet/core/lib/path.js 10:39
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:39)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   useEffect(function updatePathOptions() {
|     if (props.pathOptions !== optionsRef.current) {

> ```
>   var options = props.pathOptions ?? {};
> ```

|       element.instance.setStyle(options);
|       optionsRef.current = options;

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After some research, I found the below answers, which helped me fix them.

- [react-leaflet issues](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/881#issuecomment-858346012)
- [create-react-app issues](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9468#issuecomment-946755291)

1. First, check if your react version matches "react-leaflet" version.

   - For example in "react-leaflet" version 4.x, React v18 and Leaflet v1.8 are now
     required as peer dependency. [ref.](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)
2. Update **browserslist** in **package.json** to this:

`...    
    "browserslist": [
       ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
...`

3. Delete **.cache** directory in **node_modules** and start over.

Comment: I did all of this and still doesn't work

my packages:

"leaflet": "1.8.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",